# Is there a premade javascript script to present a circle picture, which is clickable and wherever you click it an X appears? (changeable x,y position)

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, drawing

I am creating a website for an eye doctor & need to draw a circle somewhere on an html page, and it needs to have the following functionality:

1. wherever you click it, an X will appear. (X's position is changeable, by clicking a different place in the circle)
2. i will be able to collect the (x,y) co-ordinates of the X. (back to my html page)

it was to my understanding that i can only perform this using Javascript embedded in my HTML page. Anyone heard of some javascript code which is similar to this?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 0):

Fabric Js can be useful, what you have to do is you need to add image to canvas and then you are able to draw on it and save it.

http://fabricjs.com/